# Dispatch Timer tick duplicates processes

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am implementing a timer on a project I'm working on. The timer is fired whenever a button is pressed.

On first press, it sets the duration of the timer then starts the timer. Whenever the timer ticks the program decrements the duration and prints it to the screen. It works PERFECTLY... Until you press the button again while the timer is running. When you do this the action in the tick event occurs the number of times you press the button while it's running.

My XAML looks like something like this.

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock x:Name="tBox" Text="TIMER" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle2Style}"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="timer" Text="00"  Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
</Grid>

<Button 
    Grid.Row="1" 
    Grid.Column="0"
    Content="Online" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
    Width="200"
    Height="75" Click="trigger" />
```

And my C# looks like this:

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    int duration = 0;
    int converted = 0;
    int count = 0;
    DispatcherTimer tmr = new DispatcherTimer();

    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void trigger(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        resetTimer();
        timer.Text = "30";
        tmr.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
        tmr.Tick += OnTimerTick;
            tmr.Start();
    }

    void OnTimerTick(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        converted = duration - 1;
        timer.Text = converted.ToString();
        duration = converted;
        tBox.Text = strConvert;
        count = count + 1;
        if (duration == 0)
        {
            tmr.Stop();
        }
    }

    void resetTimer()
    {
        count = 0;
        DispatcherTimer tmr = new DispatcherTimer();
        tmr.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0);
        duration = 30;
        converted = 0;
        tmr.Stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: So whats the question?  Are you wanting the user to not have the option to not press the button?? (button.enabled = false on button press event) We don't really know what  you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't add a handler for the `Tick` event in the method.  Add the `Tick` event handler, set the interval, and create the timer once when the window is created (i.e. in the constructor), and then when the button is pressed just `Start` the timer.

You should also not create a new timer when the button is pressed; you can and should re-use the existing timer.

You're not actually firing the timer multiple times.  What's happening is that you're adding the same method to the `Tick` event as a handler each time you press the button, so when the `Tick` event fires *once* your method is called that many times.  Calling `Start` on a timer that's already running won't cause it to fire multiple times, it will just reset it's interval (which I assume is desired).

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite the reset method to not create a new timer reference prior to closing the existing timer.

```
void resetTimer()
{
    count = 0;
    tmr.Stop();
    tmr.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0);
    duration = 30;
    converted = 0;
}
```

Likewise, set the Tick event handler on page load

```
// Constructor
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    timer.Text = "30";
    tmr.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
    tmr.Tick += OnTimerTick;
}

private void trigger(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        resetTimer();
        tmr.Start();
}
```

Even more so,

You should stop the timer while the tick method is executing unless you are fine with it running multiple times if the tick method takes a while to execute

```
    void OnTimerTick(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
tmr.Stop();        
converted = duration - 1;
        timer.Text = converted.ToString();
        duration = converted;
        tBox.Text = strConvert;
        count = count + 1;
tmr.Start();
    }
```

Comment: @Servy I noticed that and was updating my answer as you commented. He should be initializing the timer on the page start and only calling the `Start` and `Stop` methods via the button click event.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are adding a new instance of the OnTimerTick handler method every time trigger() is called, which I would assume from its signature is whenever the user clicks the button.

I would do one of two things; either remove/disable the button in the trigger() method body so the user can't click it multiple times, or else check the Tick event to ensure it is null (has no handlers) before attaching a reference to OnTimerTick.